# Greping from within Vim (with a pipe)

Tags: vim, grep

I want to create a 'quickfix' list (see `:help quickfix`) with all files that contain lines with "abc" but not "xyz".  I was hoping I could run the following vim ex command:

```
:grep -nHr abc * | grep -v xyz
```

Unfortunately, vim doesn't like the "pipe" and the command fails.  What is the best way to do this from within vim?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `:!...` ? (exclamation mark)

Comment: Yes.  If you use the "!", it doesn't come back as a 'quickfix' list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason I can't leave this one alone!

How about use `:!grep ... > filename` followed by `:cf filename`, which will open the output as a quickfix list.

Answer (score 5):

It's many years later, but I found more direct alternative. `cexpr` command in vim. It pretty much implements the answers from @jwd and @skeept, and is a bit more flexible because it accepts a list.

Below is an example use of my own which uses pipes. I prefix all my questions in my work notes with `Q:` to find them quickly. I wanted to use quickfix list and vim to browse through questions, viewing the most recent first.

```
:cexpr system("grep -R --line-number Q: --exclude '*~' ~/_Notes/work-log/ \| sort \| tac")
```

Relevant excerpt from the vim help.

```
:cex[pr][!] {expr}  Create a quickfix list using the result of {expr} and
            jump to the first error.
            If {expr} is a String, then each new-line terminated
            line in the String is processed using the global value
            of 'errorformat' and the result is added to the
            quickfix list.
            If {expr} is a List, then each String item in the list
            is processed and added to the quickfix list.  Non
            String items in the List are ignored.
            See |:cc| for [!].
            Examples: >
                :cexpr system('grep -n xyz *')
```

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out how to escape `:grepprg` to use a pipe.

> In my case, my `:grepprg` is based on the `lid` utility from GNU Idutils. I want the output of the `lid` program to be sorted.  this is because when I use a pattern, `lid` finds matches out of order. I want to look for a pattern like, say, `pthread.*lock` and step through the matches in order to follow lock nesting, and not jump around between files in a way that follows the internal order of the `ID` database generated by `mkid`, which interleaves the matches from different files.

The pipe requires double escaping. It seems that Vim ends up processing the value of `grepprg` as command material. If you escape the pipe just once, it is interpreted as Vim syntax.

So what I have now in my `.vimrc` is this:

```
:set grepprg=lid\ --substring\ --result=grep\ '\\<$*\\>'\ \\\|\ sort
```

The pipe is escaped as `\\\|`: an escaped backslash and an escaped pipe to produce `\|`, which undergoes one more round of processing to end up with `|`.

Based on this example, it is possible to customize your `grep` command to include arbitrary Unix plumbing.

---

If you just want to trim the results of a quicklist, or to search within the results, there is an interactive way.

After doing the `:grep`, open a buffer in a split window which contains the quicklist itself:

```
:cope[Enter]
```

To make the best use of this, learn about split windows and in particular, navigation between split windows using Ctrl-W Ctrl-W, and other Ctrl-W commands.

In the quickfix result window, you can "refine your search" by searching in the ordinary way, like in any buffer. Whatever line you navigate to, you can just hit `Enter` on that line to jump to that quicklist item in your other window. The cursor automatically goes to that window: to return to the quicklist results to search for something else, use Ctrl-W Ctrl-W.

You can also trim the quicklist results simply by deleting unwanted lines from the `:cope` buffer. The buffer is unmodifiable by default, so first you have to make sure your cursor is in that window and then:

```
 :set modifiable
```

Then you can do something like

```
 :g/xyz/d
```

to delete all results that contain `xyz`. Only the lines which remain are now part of the quickfix list.

Comment: The multiple-escaping method is nigh-unreadable. It's much easier to get around this by using `let` with literals (see help on `:let-option` and `literal-string`). You would use something like `let &grepprg='grep ... $* | sort'` in your vimrc or from the `:` prompt. Note you still have to escape `%` characters in the literal with an extra backslash, to prevent filename expansion.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in two steps:

```
:!(grep -nHr abc * | grep -v xyz >| qf.txt)
:cfile qf.txt | copen
```

if you change frequently of patterns yo probably can use a function to wrap this
the following is not perfect, but works:

```
fu! Mygrep(pat1, pat2)
  let cmd = "silent !(grep -nHr " . a:pat1 . " * | grep -v " . a:pat2 . " >| qf.txt)"
  silent exec cmd
  cfile qf.txt
  copen 
endfunction
```

and then call it using:

```
:call Mygrep("abc", "xyz")
```

it seems to work for me but I also get an error message  "trailin charathers"
(you may need to type  to clear the screen).

Comment: I like the `| copen` part.  I didn't know you could do that!  It doesn't appear the parenthesis are necessary for the external grep command.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `grepprg`, which defines what command Vim uses to execute `:grep`. It can contain pipes, though it's difficult to get the escaping correct using `:set`. If you use `:let` instead, you can pass an expression. Using a string literal for that expression provides simpler escaping rules, so you can use a more readable value. Here's an example that filters out unwanted files first, then offers multiline matching with PCRE:

```
let &gp='find . \! \( \( -path ./node_modules -o -path ./vendor -o -name '*.tags' \) -prune \) -type f -printf \%P\\0 | sort -z | xargs -0r pcre2grep -nIM '
```

All the backslashes are passed to the shell as-is with the exception of those that immediately precede `%`, as they are consumed when preventing expansion into filenames and paths.

Of course, that would affect *all* your `:grep`s but you can revert to the default command with `:set gp&`.

Comment: It does not seem to take a pipe. Or at least, this does not work for me: "set grepprg=grp\ -n\ $*\ |\ cut\ -c\ 1-$COLUMNS"  (also tried with a '\' before the '|'.) It gives "Not an editor command: cut -c 1-$COLUMNS". Maybe ]it needs to be escaped correctly, but I haven't yet figured out how.